# Python - Parallel Processing of complex Objects

Tags: python, machine-learning, parallel-processing, neural-network

Is it possible to process **complex python objects** in **parallel**?
I have multiple objects that (should) simultaneously wait for **input-parameters to arrive and to be processed and passed to another object**.

For me the main advantage of this is not only the faster processing time, but also (very important) to **keep the right order of processing the arriving inputs** etc.

I want to use this for my **python neural network** with a number x of **neurons** that are all (simulated is sufficient, as long as the order is correct) simultaneously active. They wait for input (constantly active, **object-related method**) and if something arrives they wait a certain period of time for other inputs that arrive at the same time slot and consider that in the processing for the spike (**access object related variables** to send output to connected axons from other neurons)...

Is the **multiprocessing module** of python capable of doing this?

Thank you for support :)

Comment: If you're writing a neural net application in Python, you should find a neural net library to use. Using a neural net library will probably be easier than implementing a neural net manually, and the library will run faster, too. Examples of libraries you could use are TensorFlow, Theano, and Keras. If you do use a library, your application logic should probably be single-threaded; making the application multi-threaded won't have significant advantages.

Comment: I don't want to use existing neural net libs. I want to develop my own neural network for reasons :)

Comment: Do you have any code?

Comment: In that case, although multi-threaded code may be faster, single-threaded code will definitely be easier to write. Consider making your application single-threaded to begin with and then converting it to multi-threaded.

Comment: The code is too long for posting it here. I have added more details in the post above, is now anyone able to get me a hint regarding this?

Comment: This looks interesting, it works with a board that is called "Parallela" (Kickstarter-funded, Link: https://www.parallella.org/board/), which includes a 16-core Epiphany Coprocessor: https://parallella.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=49&t=3249